# How to disallow methods other than GET on certain endpoints in Nginx?

Tags: http, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a simple proxy where I route traffic from test to a different environment. I want to restrict the HTTP method to only GET for all endpoints unless otherwise specified.

Here's a code snippet:

```
server {
    listen       8080;
    server_name  myserver.mycompany.com;
    root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

    # Load configuration files for the default server block
    include /etc/nginx.default.d/*.conf;

    location / {
        proxy_http_version 1.1.;
        proxy_set_header   "Connection", "";
        proxy_pass https://myinternalurl.mycompany.com;
        # Set default to only allow GET
        limit_except GET {
            deny all;
        }
        rewrite /v1/proxy-address/(.*) /v1/realendpoint/$1;
    }
    
    location /this/endpoint {
        proxy_http_version 1.1.;
        proxy_set_header   "Connection", "";
        proxy_pass https://myinternalurl.mycompany.com;
        # Allow POST and GET
        limit_except GET POST {
            deny all;
        }
        rewrite /v1/proxy-address/(.*) /v1/realaddress/$1;
    }
```

It seems like Nginx is reading only the first rule which is denying everything except GET, because when I try to do a POST on the '/this/endpoint/ in Postman it's returning a 403. I'm obviously missing something in my code. Any help appreciated and thank you.